# Screencast with blackboard

Tags: screen-recording

Recently I came across video tutorials on youtube which has blackboard in the background and author easily draws and writes on that board with multi color pens. This is awesome and I want to know what all things I shall need to create similar videos.

I am using camtasia studio for my recordings.

Thank you

Comment: Hi, @Santosh. Your question is pretty general. Would you like to give the details of software what you need?

For example, providing the link video tutorials on Youtube like what you have seen, specification of hardware and software (OS, open source, paid, free, and etc.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Disclaimer**: I don't mean to promote a product. I just give an example of product which I have used it before.

---

I have an experience preparing university or higher education tests using **multimedia learning**. The multimedia learning likes what you just said, *it has blackboard in the background and author easily draws and writes on that board with multicolor pens*.

The multimedia learning which I just said are [**Zenius Multimedia Learning**](https://www.zenius.net/) and [**Khan Academy**](https://www.khanacademy.org/).

By default, software/device that you should prepare in order to start screen recording are:

- **Recorder**, software that records your screen activity, voice, and sound.
- **Sketcher/Drawer**, software that allows you to sketch and draw using digital pens.
- **Pen tablet**, device that allows you to interact between your digital screen and pens.

These are below what I have explored:

- **Zenius Multimedia Learning**, after searching some sources on the internet, I found that Zenius
  Multimedia Learning used **[Windows Journal](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/create-and-personalize-handwritten-notes-using-windows-journal)** as the main sketcher/drawer software.
- **Khan Academy** (taken from this [source](https://khanacademy.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/202483430-What-software-program-equipment-is-used-to-make-Khan-Academy-videos-))

  > Sal uses a PC with:
  >
  > - Camtasia Recorder ($200*)
  > - SmoothDraw3 (Free)
  > - Wacom Bamboo Tablet ($80)
  >
  > Prior to that, he used:
  >
  > - ScreenVideoRecorder ($20)
  > - Microsoft Paint (Free)
  >
  > Mac users: In lieu of SmoothDraw, Autodesk Sketchbook Express works (free with a Wacom).
  >   *Camtasia also offers a basic version of their software called SnagIt.

I hope this is what you need. I feel something is missing here, though.

Comment: Thanks a ton! This is exactly what I was looking for. Is there any alternative for pen tablet? like some software which does similar thing with that precision with mouse.

Comment: You're welcome.

You didn't put it on your question. Please, update your question!
Let the other know what software you need exactly.